# Using ggplot scale_x_datetime() to set first date on x axis

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I've got a plot of water levels over two years. I have a column of date time (format POSIXct and displayed like 2020-03-05 17:00:00). There are 18,000 rows of data in the dataframe. The first record was the 5 March 2020. When I plot the data, the first date that appears on the x axis is Jul-20. How do I make this Mar-20?

This is the bit of code I have at the moment relevant to this part of the plot design.

```
scale_x_datetime(
      date_breaks="6 months",
      date_labels="%b-%y")
```

Heres an example of the plot.

[image]

NOTE: this is also part of ongoing data collection, so I don't want to hard code the last date.

Comment: You could customize or set your desired breaks via the `breaks` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2020-03-05 17:00:00", 
                                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                             as.Date("2022-03-05 17:00:00", 
                                     format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                             length=18000))
dat$x <- rnorm(18000)
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date)                  


ggplot(dat, aes(x=date, y=x)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks= seq(min(dat$date), max(dat$date), length=6), 
                   date_labels="%b-%y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dave, That has mostly worked. Could I just ask if length=6 is every 6 months or is it something else?

Comment: The length 6 is just to make six evenly-spaced values.  If you wanted a tick every six months, you could use: `seq(min(dat$date), max(dat$date), by = "6 months")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2020-03-05"), as.Date(Sys.Date( )), by = "6 months"), date_labels="%b-%y")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.